Copy Rotation Constraint on only X and Y flips the bone when the target bone moves to much
I want to make a mechanical thing where there's a piece that would only move like a gimbal without the local z rotating but the copy rotation constraint does work it just doesn't allow full rotations of other angles and flips. Is there a solution to this or an alternative?
Here is a video:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B01LTPHNLLg8w2IJOIQQpM30ZeKwYLGP/view?usp=sharing

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
